# how to link the phrase "to attend" when pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, weak-forms

The weak form of *to* is /tə/ and *attend* starts with /ə/.

According to the rule of linking vowel to vowel, we have to add "w" glide consonant to link two words preceding one ending with a back vowel and following one starting with any vowel.

So, do natives pronounce "to attend" as /tə wəˈtɛnd/? I feel weird when i have to follow these rules on linking vowel to vowel.

Comment: Good question. Yes, I do this, as a BrE speaker. You don't have to religiously follow this, but when speaking faster, it seems to happen naturally.

Answer (score 4):

I'm an AmE speaker, and I don't use the weak form of *to* before a word starting with a vowel. For me, /tə.wəˈtɛnd/ and /tə.əˈtɛnd/ both sound wrong (although that doesn't mean that other native English speakers don't use them).

I would say /tu.wəˈtɛnd/. I treat the word *to* (when it's unstressed) just like *the* and *a/an*, which are also pronounced differently before words starting with a vowel.

Comment: [Geoff Lindsey mentions in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfCsiF80TX0) that it's normal for *to* before a vowel not to be the weak form it normally is before consonants.

Answer (score 0):

The ə symbol just means 'some' vowel sound. They surely can be different vowels if they belong to two different words. What would sound very strange is to hear the very same vowel used in both words.

As an AmE speaker I can't recall taking the time to insert anything between the words. The difference in the sounds 'oo' as in too and 'at' in attend make enough of a contrast to prevent the two from running together as one.